# Puppet 5 File Server not working in Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

Any bad experience with file transfer on Puppet 5.4 ( Server and Agent ) running both on Ubuntu 18 LTS?

I have following configuration for example:

```
file { 'transfer test.tgz':
  path => '/opt/test.tgz',
  ensure => 'file',
  mode => '0744',
  owner => 'kisano',
  group => 'kisano',
  source => 'puppet:///files/test.tgz',
  force => true,
}
```

The file transfer is skipped due dependencies without any other debug or failure.

- removing the owner and group attribute -> the file is transferred
- running the same on a Puppet agent 5 with Ubuntu 14 LTS works like a charm
- there is no apparmor running on the Ubuntu 18 and cannot see any logs where this can be blocked maybe due security restriction

It took me some hours to realize that the due owner and group attribute cause the skipping due dependencies but why? It makes no sense..

Thank you for any input!

Comment: I just found out that if you use the uid of either  owner or group than it works like : owner => '1000',
  group => '1000',  although the latest file documentation is saying : owner
(Property: This attribute represents concrete state on the target system.)

The user to whom the file should belong. Argument can be a user name or a user ID.   Still looking maybe I am missing something

Comment: If everything is as you say then that behavior sounds buggy to me, but before I say "file a bug report", I would really like to see a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  In particular, I would like to know whether any other resources need to be in the same catalog for this failure to occur, and whether the specified user and group are present on the target node. If the user and group indeed do exist, then it may make a difference which name service module resolves their names.

Comment: It should be easy to replicate, run 2 vagrant instances of Ubuntu 18 LTS where 1 is master and the other the client  try to do a simple file transfer from the puppet fileserver and set owner + group to a non-root user using the user name. This applies only to non-root users ( for root is working ) .. The same on Ubuntu 14 running puppet 5.4 client is working as it should.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not at all what I asked.  Do follow the link in my previous comment if you're unfamiliar with the concept of a MCVE, but the main things I want to see in this case are (1) the smallest *complete* manifest or manifest set required for you to reproduce the problem, and (2) the specific information I requested about user accounts on the target system.  Additionally, the specific error messages you receive -- which are part of an MCVE, too -- would be helpful.  And if this does turn out to be a bug, those are also all things that would go into a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so I have to post an answer.
`I just found out that if you use the uid of either owner or group than it works like : owner => '1000', group => '1000', although the latest file documentation is saying : owner (Property: This attribute represents concrete state on the target system.) The user to whom the file should belong. Argument can be a user name or a user ID. Still looking maybe I am missing something`

This sounds like the client you are running on does not know the user/group *kisano*.
How do you validate users? AD, LDAP, NIS? Sounds like that is not running if you can set the UserID but not the UserName in the puppet module.
(I've had this happen to me before.)
$0.02